# Support null columns on grid

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm currently working on ASP.Net Core MVC app with [Telerik Kendo Grid](https://www.telerik.com/aspnet-core-ui/grid)

On the grid I have columns like:

```
 .Columns(columns =>
                    {
     columns.Bound(x => x.PrimaryContact.EmailAddress)
  })
```

But this is throwing an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Because PrimaryContact property can be null

To solve this I try:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.PrimaryContact != null ? x.PrimaryContact.EmailAddress : string.Empty)
```

But now is returning the error:

> InvalidOperationException: Bound columns require a field or property
> access expression.

How can I support nullable in kendo columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ClientTemplate`:

```cs
columns.Bound(x => x.PrimaryContact.EmailAddress)
       .ClientTemplate("#=PrimaryContact ? PrimaryContact.EmailAddress : ''#")
```

Check: https://feedback.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/1357413-support-null-complex-properties-in-grid-columns

Comment: It works, but now properties inside PrimaryContact are showing value "null" instead empty space, i.e : if PrimaryContact is not null but EmailAddress come true, it display it as a null

Answer (score 0):

Bind just PrimaryContact to avoid the null reference in the expression and use a template to define what you actually want the column to display:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(x => x.PrimaryContact).Template(x =>
    {
        #= x.PrimaryContact != null ? x.PrimaryContact.EmailAddress : string.Empty#
    })
})
```

This is similar to Dimitris answer (I didn't see his as I typed mine). The difference is that mine is a template rendered server side and his is rendered client side. Does it work any differently?